# Classification of finite subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}_3(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I’m curious about the finite subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}_3(\mathbb{R})$. I’ve looked around, but have only been able to find a classification of the finite subgroups in

- [$\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbb{C})$](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masda/McKay/Carrasco_Project.pdf);
- [$\mathrm{SO}(3,\mathbb{R})$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_subgroups_of_SO(3,R));
- and [$\mathrm{GL}_3(\mathbb{Z})$](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.nmj/1118798212) ...

... but not all of $\mathrm{GL}_3(\mathbb{R})$. Is there a complete classification of the finite subgroups in this setting (up to isomorphism)? If so, what is it?

---

Just for fun context, the reason I ask is because I’m curious about the construction detailed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/355502/95243) regarding building a polytope from a faithful group representation. It seems like it would be neat to actually **see** all the polyhedra you can get in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: You can "[average](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1904449/weyls-unitarian-trick)" the Euclidean dot product to get one that's invariant under such a finite group, so you only need to classify in $O(3)$.

Comment: "classification" is ambiguous, in that it can be modulo isomorphism, or, finer, modulo conjugation (and modulo conjugation by what?)

Comment: @YCor I mention that I’m looking just for subgroups up to isomorphism!

Comment: Do you consider the comment above an answer to your question? For each finite subgroup $G \subseteq \mathrm{GL}(\mathbb{R}^3)$, there is some invertible matrix $T$ such that $T G T^{-1} \subseteq \mathrm{O}(\mathbb{R}^3)$, therefore you get the same classification (in terms of isomorphism classes of groups) that you get out of $\mathrm{O}(\mathbb{R}^3)$.

Comment: @Joppy It’s very close, but there’s a bit more to do (I think). There are some finite groups appearing in $O(3)$ that are not in $SO(3)$. Of course, the missing groups are all $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ extensions of the finite groups appearing in $SO(3)$, but it’d be nice to know which extensions do appear (like $S_5$) and which do not.

Comment: It seems that an answer here has a reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61555/finite-subgroups-of-orthogonal-transformations-in-mathbbr3

Comment: @Joppy Great, thank you! Should this be closed as a duplicate, or would you like to submit that reference as an answer? I’m happy with either.

Comment: I'm proposing to close as a duplicate of the aforementioned question: [Finite subgroups of orthogonal transformations in $\mathbb{R}^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61555/finite-subgroups-of-orthogonal-transformations-in-mathbbr3)